# Stop NSPopover from closing if NSAlert dialog appears?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspopover, nsalert

Hi I have a NSStatusItem that shows a popover when clicked.  One option in the popover is to delete something; at this point I ask the user if they are sure.

The problem is that the Popover automatically closes as soon as the Alert appears.

I have tried all the different behavior settings like `NSPopoverBehaviorSemitransient`, `NSPopoverBehaviorTransient` and `NSPopoverBehaviorApplicationDefined` to no avail.

I also try catching it in `- (BOOL)popoverShouldClose:(NSPopover *)popover` but this isn't called when NSAlert appears.

Nothing seems to stop an NSAlert from closing a popover.

```
NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[alert setMessageText:msg];
[alert setInformativeText:@"Warning, delete this folder?"];
[alert setAlertStyle:NSCriticalAlertStyle];

// Show the alert
if ([alert runModal] == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn) {
```

I also tried showing the alert as a sheet in the popover which kind of works but then the popover stays around no matter if I click outside it.

Comment: How do you display the alert?

Comment: Hi again, updated question.

Comment: If the information inside the popover is not relevant for the alert, you could show it again after the alert disappears. (For a temporary solution at least..)

Comment: Good idea, that works better than having to click through everything to get back to where you were.  Cheers

Comment: How about adjusting your design so that you can ask for confirmation within the popover? For example, display "Are you sure?" next to the delete button and make the delete button actually delete.

Comment: This particular delete option is within a right click context menu on a NSTableView.  Re-displaying the popover after the dialog is the preferred workaround for now.  Thanks anyway tbodt.

Comment: The other option I will eventually do is to create another popup under the tableRow that the user wants to delete and mimic the Alert Dialog.  Popovers can chain without closing.

Comment: Temporarily setting the behavior to `NSPopoverBehaviorSemitransient` or `NSPopoverBehaviorApplicationDefined` works for me.

Comment: Is that from a popup shown on an NSStatusItem Willeke?

Comment: No it wasn't, but I tried on a status item. It is looking weird but it works.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Maybe because i'm targeting 10.7.